# execute .exe file from web application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to execute .exe file from the web application
i use the following code

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\backup_restore.exe";
        p.Start();
    }
```

but i get %1 is not a valid Win32 application error
what could be solution for this

I have also make Enable 32-bit Application TRUE in DefaultAppPool

Comment: Have you made sure the file name c:\\backup_restore.exe exists and that you can run it on that server simply by clicking on it? That error seems to indicate the exe is not valid, either corrupted or not an executable in the first place.

Comment: yes i have file name backup_restore.exe in c drive  and it runs when i double click it

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message? Is it YOSD since you are calling it from a Web form?

Comment: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Source Error: 


Line 32:         Process p = new Process();
Line 33:         p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\backup_restore.exe";
Line 34:         p.Start();
Line 35:      
Line 36:     }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610091/not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812486/event-id-7000-and-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-error-message-when-you-start-a-service

Comment: I have viewed this as well but no result